# Issue while enabling CMS https

Tags: content-manager, sites-9.1, https

I am trying to enable Content Manager URL to HTTPS. I am following the  documentation. I am getting following Error. Please let me know is there anything I am missing.

Could not find path "\LocalMachine\Personal" it does not exists
D:\SDL Web\bin\Configuration Scripts\Support\Utilities.ps1:289 char:21
$Cert = dir cert:$StoreLocation$StoreName

Comment: Please check if the SSL certificate is imported properly and provide more details on the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewed the Error and the Script noticed that the issue is related to Store Name, please go to IIS and open the Server Certificate and copy the Certificate Store Name and change the $StoreName  and try to run the script again.

Let us know if it works!

Comment: Thanks it helped and now its working as expected